# AlarmManager not work if activity is kill

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a AlarmManager using a Calendar from users input (stored in a object), my goal is to schelude notifications from this Calendar, if the app is running everything goes well, but if it was swipped away from recents apps the notification doesnt comes. My code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventReciver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent,0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar horaInicial = materiaBuffer.getHoraInicial(); //Take Calendar from materiaBuffer object
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horaInicial.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, horaInicial.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

In the AndroidManifest I just change:

```
<receiver android:name=".etc.EventReciver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

My EventReciver:

```
public class EventReciver extends BroadcastReceiver{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.i("Lauri", "EventReciver");
      // I removed the code for the notification, it works fine
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `swipped away from recents apps` sometimes means kill the whole app process.

Comment: @AvatarQing Some way to keep the AlarmManager?

Comment: I have no good ideas, I think there is no way to keep alarm work after force kill the process, even in some famous third-party alarm clock app. Maybe you should search for the ways to keep the app alive forever.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @DavidWasser in a Asus Zenfone 3, Android 7

Answer (score -1):

I tested it on Lolipop. this code works fine, even app is not running

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

In `maifest`

```
<receiver
  android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true" />
```

Receiver Class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Alarm Received");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alerm Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm")
            .setContentText("This code works!")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
 }
}
```

Comment: could you explain your answer a little bit, instead of just thowing some code at us?

Comment: No, doesn't work. Keeps just showing the notification while the app is running. Any other idea?

Comment: @TanbirHossen, i forgot to call you

Comment: @TanbirHossen Nothing, I just can't get it done... Maybe is the android version? I am using Android 7 to test it